# Отправка HTTP запроса и сохранение файла из ответа (Java )

Tags: java

Есть URL.

**Нужно чтобы был отправлен запрос :** т.е. Java перешла по ссылке.

**И получила ответ :** в виде Wav файла,который необходимо воспроизвести.

Как это реализовать?Какие дополнительные библиотеки нужно подключить?

Посмотрел похожие темы,есть реализованная на PHP. Но нужна Java.

Отправить запрос насколько мне известно можно так :

```
   URL url = new URL("https://");
   url.openConnection();
```

А вот как полученный ответ в виде Waw файла сохранить и воспроизвести.Хотя сохранять необязательно.

ещё увидел вот такую конструкцию

```
 import java.applet.Applet;
 import java.applet.AudioClip;
 import java.net.URL;

  public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
        URL url = new URL("file:youraudiofile.wav" );
        AudioClip ac = Applet.newAudioClip(url);
        ac.play();

        System.out.println("Press any key to exit.");
        System.in.read();
        ac.stop();
      } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
      }
    }
```

Вся проблема в том,что когда переходишь по ссылке итоговая страница уже воспроизводит звук в браузере.
А нужно чтобы Java сохранила файл,дала ему расширение.

Пример простой попытки включить аудио-файл:

```
package sayme;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.*;
import java.applet.*;

public class URLReader {

    public static void main(String a[]) {
        try {
           String str1 = "http://dll.zf.fm/music/f/7e/clean_bandit_feat_sean_paul__anne-marie_-_rockabye_(zf.fm).mp3";
  URL url = new URL(str1); // 1
            AudioClip clip = Applet.newAudioClip(url);
            clip.play();
        } catch (java.net.MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

я не слышу звук,когда выполняется код.
даже если после поставить вот так :

```
clip.play();
Thread.sleep(10000);
```

программа отработает 15 секунд и выключится.

программа отлично работает с файлами которые имеются в системе,а не в интернете.
естественно,если перейти по этой ссылке в браузере - он включит это трек в браузере.
А вот воспроизвести так сказать из кода он не даёт.
В чем проблема?

Comment: я вот думаю,может просто файл нужно сохранять при переходе по ссылке,потом делать новый класс,который включает загруженный файл?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Отправить запрос насколько мне известно можно так :
>
> URL url = new URL("https://");
>     url.openConnection();
>   Цитата

Это не совсем так...

```
URL url = new URL("https://");
```

- просто создается инстанс URL.

```
url.openConnection();
```

- создается инстанс коннекта (URLCOnnection). Но никаких данных еще никуда не отправлено. Это только заготовка.

Помимо этого недурно еще установить параметры коннекта: будет ли он принимать/отправлять данные (setDoInput(), setDoInput()), метод запроса (GET, POST, PUT  и т.д.), таймаут коннекта, указать заголовки запроса.

В качестве примера:

```
proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("<host>", <port>));
conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(proxy);
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setUseCaches(false);
conn.setConnectTimeout(60000);
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
// подготовили коннект

// Т.к. запрос у нас GET, то сразу принимаем входящие данные.
// Вот тут как раз (при открытии InputStream ) и происходит отправка GET запроса на сервер.
InputStream inStream = conn.getInputStream();
// Т.к. файл у нас бинарный, открываем ReadableByteChannel и создаем файл
ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(conn.getInputStream());
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("<имя_файла_для_сохранения>");

// Перенаправляем данные из ReadableByteChannel прямо канал файла.
// Говорят, так быстрее, чем по одному байту вычитывать из потока и писать в файл.
long filePosition = 0;
long transferedBytes = fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, filePosition, Long.MAX_VALUE);

while(transferedBytes == Long.MAX_VALUE){
    filePosition += transferedBytes;
    transferedBytes = fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, filePosition, Long.MAX_VALUE);
}
rbc.close();
fos.close();
```

Если прокси нет, то

```
 conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(Proxy.NO_PROXY);
```

А вообще это хардкорный способ. Гораздо удобнее использовать библиотеку [Apache HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi)

Код грубоват, но должен с работать. Но сначала советую попробовать скачать файл на более простом ресурсе, где нет "охранных систем":

```
public class NewClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    try{
        URL url = new URL("http://dll.zf.fm/music/f/7e/clean_bandit_feat_sean_paul__anne-marie_-_rockabye_(zf.fm).mp3");
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(Proxy.NO_PROXY);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        //conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setConnectTimeout(60000);
        conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
        // подготовили коннект

        // Т.к. запрос у нас GET, то сразу принимаем входящие данные.
        // Вот тут как раз (при открытии InputStream ) и происходит отправка GET запроса на сервер.
        InputStream inStream = conn.getInputStream();
        // Т.к. файл у нас бинарный, открываем ReadableByteChannel и создаем файл
        ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(conn.getInputStream());
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("qwe.mp3");

        // Перенаправляем данные из ReadableByteChannel прямо канал файла.
        // Говорят, так быстрее, чем по одному байту вычитывать из потока и писать в файл.
        long filePosition = 0;
        long transferedBytes = fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, filePosition, Long.MAX_VALUE);

        while(transferedBytes == Long.MAX_VALUE){
            filePosition += transferedBytes;
            transferedBytes = fos.getChannel().transferFrom(rbc, filePosition, Long.MAX_VALUE);
        }
        rbc.close();
        fos.close();
    }catch(Exception e){
        InputStreamReader inStream = new InputStreamReader(conn.getErrorStream());
        char[] cbuf = new char[1];
        String result= "";
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(inStream);

        while (in.read(cbuf) != -1) {
            result += String.valueOf(cbuf);
        }
        System.out.println("result:" + result);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: А уже опосля, когда файл будет загружен, можно использовать вторую заготовку из Ваш его поста. Но возможно, есть способ воспроизводить прямо из входящего потока запроса...

Comment: что-то не срабатывает код,вбрасывает,что не может перейти по ссылке. Будьте добры,если не сложно написать полный класс,который к примеру скачает трек из этой ссылки http://dll.zf.fm/music/f/7e/clean_bandit_feat_sean_paul__anne-marie_-_rockabye_(zf.fm).mp3

Comment: это же пример, конечно он не заработает "как есть")

Comment: я вот и посмотрел что с ним можно сделать) потому хочется реализовать его) не поможете?

Comment: вы поможете с реализацией?

Comment: хм... похоже на сайте какая-то защита от скачивания "в лоб" стоит.

я получаю такой ответ:
Error 1010 Ray ID: 324ceb41e7df4f0e • 2017-01-21 18:44:41 UTC

Access denied

What happened?

The owner of this website (dll.zf.fm) has banned your access based on your browser's signature (324ceb41e7df4f0e-ua21).

CloudFlare Ray ID: 324ceb41e7df4f0e • Your IP: 136.169.141.198 • Performance & security by CloudFlare

Comment: куда он сохраняет файл? У меня вылез html-код просто

Comment: ахахаххахах работает) ура) вы гений)

Comment: а с другим форматом кроме mp3 работать будет?

Comment: работает под другие форматы)